# How to correctly use Devise + Confirmable + fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm using Devise + Confirmable for user authentication and Minitest + Capybara + fixtures for testing. I can make working logged in tests for users as long as I included some form of login (either with the helper `login_as(@user)` or going to the login page with Capybara) and the line`@user.confirm` before running.

How can I confirm users in the fixture itself though so I don't have to include this line every time.

Right now I have:

`confirmed_at: Time.now`

in the yml, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Here is a working sample test, if it's useful for illustration:

```
def setup
    @user = users(:user)
  end

   test 'user should be redirected to profile edit on first login' do
     @user.confirm
     visit(new_user_session_path)
     fill_in('user_email', :with => @user.email)
     fill_in('user_password', :with => 'foobar')
     click_button('Log in')
     assert_current_path(edit_user_registration_path)
   end
```

and the user fixture:

```
user:
  email: test1@example.com
  confirmed_at: Time.now
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, 'foobar') %>
  sign_in_count: 0
```

Comment: So the user was created, saved and not yet confirmed? You want to edited that database field manually?

Comment: As far as I know the fixtures are not actually saved to the DB. When I look at the users in the development DB neither of the two fixture users are there.

Comment: Hello, I updated my answer. The solution of the problem is found hear. You need to configure it as in the guide and call the method  user.confirm! inside the module ControllerMacros method def login_user

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)#controller-specs

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio the guide moved at https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-(and-RSpec) but the `Date.today` stated there doesn't work (_non funziona_ :/)! Here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75052159/824806

Answer (score 2):

I updated my answer. The solution of the problem is found here. You need to configure it as in the guide and call the method  user.confirm! inside the module ControllerMacros method def login_user

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)#controller-specs

Open source github page of a complete Devise Rspec Project including testing

https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise/blob/master/spec/features/users/sign_in_spec.rb

---

you are trying to set

```
User.confirmed_at = Time.now
```

but `confirmed_at` has `datetime` datatype at least in my postegresql db, so this may depend on the db you are using.

```
confirmed_at: datetime
```

So this is the `Time.now` format

```
pry(main)> Time.now
=> 2017-03-14 11:14:06 +0100
```

While this is is the `User.confirmed_at` format

```
user.confirmed_at
=> Sun, 05 Mar 2017 15:05:03 UTC +00:00
```

So you should use a compatible format/variable, try to search the DateTime class for a compatible format that includes the UTC as `DateTime.now` returns:

```
[40] pry(main)> DateTime.now
=> Tue, 14 Mar 2017 11:19:25 +0100
```

`DateTime` has a `utc()` method. If I run this it is almost what is needed.

```
DateTime.civil(2005, 2, 21, 10, 11, 12, Rational(-6, 24)).utc

DateTime.civil(2005, 2, 21, 10, 11, 12, Rational(-6, 24)).utc
=> 2005-02-21 16:11:12 UTC
```

Check the DateTime api and if needed you can check the utc() method on github

```
DateTime.civil(2005, 2, 21, 10, 11, 12, Rational(-6, 24))     # => Mon, 21 Feb 2005 10:11:12 -0600
DateTime.civil(2005, 2, 21, 10, 11, 12, Rational(-6, 24)).utc # => Mon, 21 Feb 2005 16:11:12 UTC


# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb, line 168
def utc
  utc = new_offset(0)

  Time.utc(
    utc.year, utc.month, utc.day,
    utc.hour, utc.min, utc.sec + utc.sec_fraction
  )
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-utc

Comment: I think this is on the right track, but dateTime.now didn't work for me. The DB is the default SQLite setup. After I read this I found [SQLite should take date('now')](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users) in the Devise docs. I've tried this syntax, but no luck.

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone There is a method to confirm devise user `.skipconfirmation!`. When you create the user with `user = User.new` you call `user.skip_confirmation!` and then you save

Comment: This wouldn't pull the user data out of the fixture though would it?

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone Sorry. I can not answer you right now. I will find you a solution tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this! The instructions that you added do work, but not for fixtures + Minitest (they are for Rspec + FactoryGirl). In the end I was able to make this work with a version of this Using Minitest + FactoryGirl, but was never successful in making it work with fixtures.

If any users stumble on this later, I suggest that you just use FactoryGirl and the method that Fabrizio has linked to.

Comment: Check my answer to see how to use fixtures only. It works for me out of the box in rails 7 within a minitest IntegrationTest.

Answer (score 1):

I had a tough time figuring out why the devise test helper method `sign_in users(:one)` did not work. It was due to the usage of the `:confirmable` module. I managed to fix the fixtures like so:

```yaml
# fixtures/users.yml
one: 
  email: "user1@test"
  confirmed_at: <%= Time.current %>
```

(The OP does not include the ERB tags `<%= %>`. Also note that in rails 7 you do not need to change the file extension to yml.erb, as the ERB within fixtures is parsed anyway)