# User Sign in not working in Rails Test Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, devise, minitest

I am trying to write and learn about test cases in ruby on rails. My sites controller has authenticate_user! before_action hook in my SitesController.

I have Devise gem already installed in the application through which I authenticate users normally in my application. I also have devise_invitable and simple_token_authentication(for authentication in api calls) gems.

Here is what my concerned files look like

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 acts_as_token_authenticatable
 default_scope { order(email: :asc) }

 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # , :lockable, ,  and :omniauthable
 devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
     :confirmable, :trackable, :timeoutable, :lockable

 include UserStudies
 include UserAgreements

 has_person_name
 


 # Validations
  validates :name, presence: true
  before_destroy :check_for_studies


end
```

**config/environments/test.rb**

```
# The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
# test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
# your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
# and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!

Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  config.cache_classes = false
  config.action_view.cache_template_loading = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Configure public file server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    "Cache-Control" => "public, max-age=#{1.hour.to_i}"
  }
  routes.default_url_options = {host: "localhost", port: 5000}
  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.cache_store = :null_store

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system in a temporary directory.
  config.active_storage.service = :test

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  # Raises error for missing translations.
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

**test/test_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require_relative "../config/environment"
require "rails/test_help"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
  parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

**test/controllers/sites_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class SitesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  
  setup do
    puts users(:one).inspect
    sign_in users(:one)   
    @site = sites(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get sites_url
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

**test/fixtures/users.yml**

```
# Read about fixtures at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

# This model initially had no columns defined. If you add columns to the
# model remove the '{}' from the fixture names and add the columns immediately
# below each fixture, per the syntax in the comments below
#
one: 
  email: umair.one@gmail.com
  first_name: Test 
  last_name: one
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, '123456') %>

# column: value
#
two:
  email: umair.two@gmail.com
  first_name: Test
  last_name: two
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, '123456') %>
# column: value
```

**test/fixtures/sites.yml**

```
# Read about fixtures at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

one:
  code: MyString
  name: MyString
  street_address: MyString
  city: MyString
  state: MyString
  zip_code: MyString
  phone: MyString

two:
  code: MyString
  name: MyString
  street_address: MyString
  city: MyString
  state: MyString
  zip_code: MyString
  phone: MyString
```

**db/schema.rb**

```
create_table "sites", id: :uuid, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "code"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "street_address"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.string "zip_code"
    t.string "country"
    t.string "phone"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

create_table "users", id: :uuid, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "unconfirmed_email"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "time_zone"
    t.datetime "accepted_terms_at"
    t.datetime "accepted_privacy_at"
    t.datetime "announcements_read_at"
    t.boolean "admin"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "invitation_token"
    t.datetime "invitation_created_at"
    t.datetime "invitation_sent_at"
    t.datetime "invitation_accepted_at"
    t.integer "invitation_limit"
    t.string "invited_by_type"
    t.uuid "invited_by_id"
    t.integer "invitations_count", default: 0
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.string "authentication_token", limit: 30
    t.index ["authentication_token"], name: "index_users_on_authentication_token", unique: true
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["invitation_token"], name: "index_users_on_invitation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["invitations_count"], name: "index_users_on_invitations_count"
    t.index ["invited_by_id"], name: "index_users_on_invited_by_id"
    t.index ["invited_by_type", "invited_by_id"], name: "index_users_on_invited_by_type_and_invited_by_id"
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

When I run my test case despite having sign_up user inside the test controller I am getting this error.

```
Failure:
SitesControllerTest#test_should_get_index [/home/app/test/controllers/sites_controller_test.rb:13]:
Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <302: Found> redirect to <http://localhost:5000/users/sign_in>
Response body: <html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost:5000/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

I have followed [GoRails](https://gorails.com/episodes/devise-test-helpers) tutorial to setup devise authentication in test controllers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am curious if `users(:one)` is saved in your test Database, cause if it's not then `sign_in users(:one)` isn't going to work.

Comment: I have users(:one) in my fixture file users.yml

Comment: Do you have any factories for the users?

Comment: No, this is just using fixtures.

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: its rails version 6

Comment: Check https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#test-helpers to see verify your setup is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this by adding `confirmed_at` and `confirmation_sent_at` to my fixture. My fixture looks like this:

```
admin:
  email: 'admin@example.com'
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, '<PASSWORD>') %>
  confirmed_at: <%= Time.zone.now - 1.hour %>
  confirmation_sent_at: <%= Time.zone.now - 2.hours %>
  admin: true
```